# Scheduled end date in a custom report

Tags: scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I have custom report for scheduled batches i need fields included in the report Start date and END DATE of the scheduled jobs. I have checked these objects AsyncApexJob,CronTrigger,CronJobDetail but couldnt find these fields.

In which object i can find them as i need to include them in my custom report
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can clearly see that in `CronTrigger` object.

Fire the SOQL on `CronJobDetail` and get the Id of the job.

```
SELECT
        Id,
        JobType,
        Name
FROM CronJobDetail
```

Then use that ID on SOQL on `CronTrigger` and fetch fields `StartTime` and `EndTime`

```
SELECT EndTime,
        StartTime
FROM CronTrigger
WHERE CronJobDetailId = '08a7F00002BLgJ2QAL'
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, But i need when the date when batch will end on. for example i have scheduled my batch from jan1st2021 to 31st december 2021 so i need these days in the query.

Comment: Yeah so endTime will give you the date your batch will end on. Its a datetime field, get the date from that.  I still dont see any issue in that. `cronTrigger.get(0).EndTime.date()`,